# Trying to replicate UIScrollView in a web view: why can't I scroll left?

Tags: ios, css, webkit, scroll, css-position

I'm trying to replicate UIScrollView's behavior with web content in an iPhone app. There will be a number of equal height items that are about as wide as the whole screen, and I want the user to be able to scroll through them horizontally. Think something like the Photos app, or sort of like Coverflow. The content is today's news, tomorrow's news, and then yesterday's news.

I've got a bunch of HTML and CSS code written. Each "day" corresponds to an item. Here's the code (I've added borders for illustration purposes)

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
    }

    div#todayContainer {
        position:relative;
        height:250px;
        overflow-x:auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        border:solid 1px yellow;
    }

    div#todayContent {
        position:absolute;
        left:-320px;
        width:960px;
        height:100%;
        overflow-x:auto;
        border:solid 1px blue;
    }

    .day {
        position:absolute;
        left:330px;
        width:300px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:red;
    }

    .nextDay {
        position:absolute;
        left:650px;
        width:300px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:green;
    }

    .previousDay {
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        width:300px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:orange;
    }
    </style>
<body>
    <div id="todayContainer">
        <div id="todayContent">
            <div class="previousDay">
                Test previousDay
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="nextDay">
                Test nextDay
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Everything looks OK on run...

[image]

... and if I scroll to the right a bit, looks like everything's going to work!

[image]

But then when I try to scroll left, it's a no go. But since I have touch overflow scrolling on, I can "bounce" a little to the left to see the content I intend to be there is there...

[image]

I just can't scroll it completely into view. Also: notice that the scroll indicator at the bottom seems to think that it's already at the leftmost point of the content. But, I really want it to think that it's only about 1/3 of the way of the through.

Any help?

Comment: I would be interested in how you get tomorrow's news. ;) Maybe this comment raises the question in the search results and thus draws attention. Good luck!

Comment: Wound up supporting iOS 6 at minimum and switching to a UIPageViewController with horizontal scrolling, each View Controller controls a view with a Web View in it.